# Apache web server doesn't product core dump on segmentation faults

Tags: apache, coredump

i have added CoreDumpDirectory /tmp in httpd.conf

```
mkdir /tmp
chown apache:apache /tmp
chmod 0777 /tmp

ulimit -c unlimited
service httpd restart
```

but no `core.*` dump files were generated when segment fault occured, any advice?

my system is CentOS6.2 x64 (virtual machine)

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/security/limits.conf` file and see if this line is set to 0:

```
* hard core 0
```

Esentially, anything where the 3rd word is `core` and see if eithe rthe first word is `*` or `apache` or something relevant. You can comment that line out by adding a `#` to the beginning of the line. Then run:

```
sysctl -p
```